# How to queries on "many-to-many" SQL tables?

Tags: sql, many-to-many

If I want to create a many to many relation in SQL I have to do it with 3 tables, something like this:

```
create table testCases(
id int(11) auto_increment,
testcase varchar(200),
primary key(id))


create table requirements(
id int(11) auto_increment,
requirements varchar(200),
primary key(id))
```

and a third table map the relationship

```
 create table matchRequirementsToTests(
 requirements varchar(200),
 testcase varchar(200),
primary key(requirements, testcase),
foreign key (requirements) references Requirements(id),
foreign key(test case) references Test_cases(id))
```

I've seen other examples, some add "constraints".

But I cannot find any example on how to further use this "many-to-many" table. (MySQL or SQL Server).
I mean, How do I have to specify the relations in order to perform queries now?

regards

Comment: You may not need to put 'requirements' and 'testcase' in the third table if they are the same thing as in the first two.

Comment: The relationships are already specified by your foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

Querying multiple tables is called a join operation in SQL. Just google SQL join, it's very basic.

In fact, it is not mandatory to respect the defined relationships when querying the database.

The relationships just tell the database how to maintain data integrity. Basically, it means that valid values for a field are only those existing in the "foreign" table.

As a side note, the correct term is "relationship" or, more generally, "constraint". "Relation" is a term used to describe the table itself (in relational algebra).